# How can I delete my account from Agilefant?

Tags: user-accounts

I created an account on [Agilefant](http://agilefant.com). But now I want to delete the account due to some reason and want to re-create it. How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The [official FAQ](http://agilefant.com/support/faq/) says:

*Currently, **you can’t delete users**. The problem in deleting users is dealing with their possible logged spent effort – should they disappear? In most cases no.*

*If you have suggestions on how to handle this, do bring it up on the forums!*

You should probably deal with the problem that makes you want to delete and recreate an account differently.

Comment: I want my colleagues on the same forum i.e. in the same team. But currently 2 of us have created account differently.

Answer (score 0):

Agilefant owner / support person is always online there. It can be found at the bottom of the site.

> **Questions? Chat with Dr. Agilefant!**

I told him my problem and asked him to delete my account and he did it.